# Need to view final SQL operator generated by the JDBC Adapter

Tags: sql, jdbc, db2, invoke, websphere-process-server

"Service Invoke" primitive (WID) taking part in outbound processing with JDBC Adapter.

How can I check the final SQL select which this whole processing sends to DB?
May be db2 provide some way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the JDBC trace by adding the `traceFile` option to the JDBC URL:

```
jdbc:db2://<hostname>:<port>/<dbname>:traceFile=/tmp/jdbc.trc;
```

More info [in the manual.](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_cjvjcdig.html?lang=en)

Comment: thanx but not any trace file appeared after adding that magic into *.import file and even after redeployment my program on the server

Answer (score 0):

this helps
[Enabling trace for a Websphere-managed datasource](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=71&uid=swg21196160#wasconnection)

p.s. thanx to mustaccio's answer - he gaves me the idea of searching in the right direction